# How can i lock some rows for inserting in Django?

Tags: python, django, multithreading, django-rest-framework

I want to batch create users for admin. But, the truth is `make_password` is a time-consuming task. Then, if I returned the created user-password list util the new users are all created, it will let front user waiting for a long time. So, i would like to do somethings like code showed below. Then, I encountered a problem. Cause I can not figure out how to lock the user_id_list for creating, someone registered during the thread runtime will cause an `Dulplicate Key Error` error thing like that.
So, I am looking forward your good solutions.

```
    def BatchCreateUser(self, request, context):
        """批量创建用户"""
        num = request.get('num')
        pwd = request.get('pwd')
        pwd_length = request.get('pwd_length') or 10

        latest_user = UserAuthModel.objects.latest('id')  # retrieve the lastest registered user id
        start_user_id = latest_user.id + 1  # the beginning user id for creating
        end_user_id = latest_user.id + num  # the end user id for creating
        user_id_list = [i for i in range(start_user_id, end_user_id + 1)]  # user id list for creating

        raw_passwords = generate_cdkey(num, pwd_length, False)  # generating passwords
        Thread(target=batch_create_user, args=(user_id_list, raw_passwords)).start()  # make a thread to perform this time-consuming task


        user_password_list = list(map(list, zip(*[user_id_list, raw_passwords])))  # return the user id and password immediately without letting front user waiting so long
        return {'results': user_password_list}
```

Comment: Should I use table-level lock things like that?

Comment: have you tried creating new users using a 'Transaction'? i.e. first create new users using a Transaction and if users with are created, then you can set password for those users using user_ids, later.

Comment: Oh, I have not tried using transaction yet. It maybe a simple solution for this. But i did not understand ` those users` clearly, did u mean those who registered during thread run for batch creating user.

Comment: ^yes, exactly. what i simply meant is try creating user/users first without password and if successfully created then set password.

Comment: Oh, good suggestion. I will try it.